# Cooking Belgian Waffles in waffle iron

Tags: equipment

My waffle iron does not cook Belgian waffle enough (they are not brown on the outside but are cooked on the inside) at the recommended temperature and time. what should I do, raise the temperature or cook them long?

Answer (score 1):

I would first try cooking them longer. Raising the temp can also work, but you run the risk of burning whatever oil you are spraying onto the waffle iron, which can taste off (not a big risk) and will smoke up your home.

Without knowing about your batter, I'd suggest adding more sugar in some form. That's often the culprit in homemade pancake/waffle batters, we neglect to use enough sugar. More sugar will allow the outside to caramelize more, which is the browning you see. (Ok, it's a malliard reaction)

Browning occurs when sugars and proteins (in the flour, eggs, milk, etc) interact under high temps. So not enough of either, and you will end up with a paler product no matter what.